# Include module from Nexus in Play Framework 1.2

Tags: playframework, dependencies, nexus

I have project on Play Framework 1.2.7 and module **validation-1.0.jar** in local Nexus repository. Module artifact is **validation**, groupName is **ru.fab.edu**.

In dependencies.yml

```
require:
- ru.fab.edu -> validation 1.0

repositories:
- Nexus:
   type: http
   artifact: "http://url/nexus/content/repositories/releases/"
   contains:
     - ru.fab.edu -> *
```

After `play deps —sync` validation-1.0.jar is loaded, but this file is a html code of Nexus page. How to describe this dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right dependency describes like this:

```
require:
    - ru.fab.edu -> validation 1.2.0-SNAPSHOT

repositories:
    - Nexus:
        type: iBiblio
        root: "http://url/nexus/content/repositories/public"
        contains:
            - ru.fab.edu -> *
```